# Allow users to delete or answer Facebook comments on my website or from Facebook

Tags: facebook, comments

I am creating a website, something like business directory. I want to allow my users to have Facebook comments on the pages.  I read that I should connect their comments with their Facebook ID so they can be allowed to delete them.   I wanted to know, can my users answer or delete those comments directly from Facebook, or must they be only on my website to answer?

Answer (score 1):

To get Facebook comments working on your site you need to [follow Facebook's instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/).  They will give you a snippet of javascript code to put on your site where you want the comments to show up.

Then users can comment on that page.  By default their comments are shared on Facebook.  Replies on facebook will also show up on your site.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. My users have their profile pages, so i want to add facebook comments on their profile pages. If a comment is placed on user X profile page, is it possible for that user to be notified about the comment on his Facebook profile?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Facebook API for monitoring or deleting comments.

Or, if you want to have just a comment box where user can comment or delete their comments, use Facebook's social plugin.